# Java Generic Binary Search Tree cannot compare T types

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, data-structures, tree

Here's the code for a generic Binary Search Tree. I haven't implemented the search function yet because I already got errors on lines: 1, 2 and 3, which I have pointed out in the code. The error says:

> The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T.

So, I guess the compiler doesn't know how to compare these types or something similar. Now, I did a little bit of research, and I found out that it has got something to do with Comperable and compareTo method, but as a java rookie myself, I haven't managed to fix the code.  Any ideas as to how to fix it?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Tree<T> 
    { private Node<T> root = null;

    public boolean insert(T element) 
        { if (isEmpty()) 
            { root = new Node<T>(element);
            return true; }// empty tree, Node could be inserted, return true

         Node<T> current = root; // start at root
         Node<T> parent;         // the current Node's parent

         do 
            {parent = current;

             if (element < current.element) // 1
                 current = current.left; // go to left
              else if (element > current.element) //2
                 current = current.right; // go to right
              else 
                 return false; }  // duplicates are NOT allowed, element could not be inserted -> return false 
             while (current != null);

         Node<T> node = new Node<T>(element);

         if (element < current.element) // 3
             parent.left = node;
          else 
             parent.right = node;

         return true; } // node successfully inserted


    public boolean isEmpty() { return root == null; }

    private static class Node<T>  // static member class
        { Node<T> left  = null;
        Node<T> right = null;
        final T element;

        Node(T element) { this.element = element; } }

    }
```

Comment: You need to constrain `T` to implement `Comparable`: `Tree<T extends Comparable<T>>`. Then use `element.compareTo(current.element) < 0`.

Comment: @Andy Turner thaks man, that fixed it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison operators like `<`, `<=`, `>=` and `>` are only defined for numeric types.

To compare other types, you need to either:

- Use a type which implements `Comparable`, e.g. `String`. You can do this by adding a constraint to the type variable:

  ```
  public class Tree<T extends Comparable<T>>
  ```

  This means that you are able to invoke the `compareTo` method:

  ```
  if (element.compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
  ```
- Pass in a `Comparator`, which is able to compare instances of the type:

  ```
  public boolean insert(T element, Comparator<? super T> comparator)
  ```

  And then use this to compare the elements:

  ```
  if (comparator.compare(element, current.element)) {
  ```

Comment: but if I go for the second option, with the Comparator, then when I want to insert an element, instead of insert(2.3) for instance, how do I call the insert function? insert(2.3, ???) ?

Comment: Make the comparator a constructor parameter.

Comment: I dont... I don't understand